# TypeError: <object> is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, django, object, python-2.x

I am trying to encode an object into json using `json.dumps()` in Django, however when I pass in a python object, it raises this error.

```
TypeError: <OrgInvite: OrgInvite object> is not JSON serializable
```

I was under the assumption that even though JSON can only encode certain data types, one of those data types were objects. I read another question on Stack Overflow that a good way to get around this is by creating a dictionary out of the object using `.__dict__` I tried this and it is saying that one of the keys in my new dictionary, _state is not serializable. I am not sure where this _state key came from, and was wondering is there a way to convert my object into a dictionary without that extra field, so I can encode it into JSON ?

model:

```
class OrgInvite(models.Model):
    token = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True, null=False)
    account_id = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    org_id = models.ForeignKey(Org, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    used = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

view:

```
def get_invite(token):
    if not token:
        raise Exception("Invitation token is not specified")

    invitation = OrgInvite.objects.get(token=token)
    if not invitation:
        raise Exception("Invitation token is invalid.")

    return invitation

def invite_accept_redirect(token):
    # """ -Redirects to the accept invite frontend view with pre-fetched data. """

    try:
        invite = get_invite(token)
        if not invite:
            raise Exception("Invitation token is invalid")
        if invite.used:
            invite = {'used': True}
    except:
        invite = {'invalid': True}
        raise Exception("Resource not found.")

    base = "home/accept"

    url = '{}/{}?data={}'.format(base, token, urllib.quote_plus(json.dumps(invite.__dict__)))

    return redirect(url)
```

console:

```
>>> oi = OrgInvite.objects.get(token=100) 
>>> oi
<OrgInvite: OrgInvite object>
>>> oix = oi.__dict__
>>> oix
{'used': False, 'name': u'', '_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x10377a610>, 'email': u'', 'token': u'100', 'org_id_id': 101, 'account_id_id': 301, 'is_admin': False, 'id': 1}
>>> json.dumps(oix)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 244, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x10377a610> is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: The namedtuple class uses `._asdict()` and returns the thing as dictionary. It may be valuable to use that same interface for your code.

Comment: @WayneWerner  What are you talking about?  Django models and their serialization have nothing to do with `namedtuple`

Comment: returning a dictionary via an `._asdict()` method. I mention `namedtuple` as a source in the standard library that already does that. Perhaps it's not quite appropriate for the OP's case, but may accomplish what they need (or others who have a *similar* problem).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `__dict__` gives all the attributes of the instance, but you don't want all that extra baggage - for the purposes of serialization, you are only interested in the fields.

Your model does not contain anything special so the built-in helper function `model_to_dict` should be enough for your needs:

```
import json
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

oi = OrgInvite.objects.get(token=100) 
oi_dict = model_to_dict(oi)
oi_serialized = json.dumps(oi_dict)
```

Your example was simple, only containing `CharField`, `BooleanField`, and `ForeignKey` all of which we can dump to `json` trivially.

For more complicated models, you might consider writing your own [serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/).  In this case, I recommend using the popular [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) which does all the work for you.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class OrgInviteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrgInvite
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm ! I will keep this in mind moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `invite.__dict__`, it's going to give you a dictionary of all data related to one `invite` object. However, the dict's values are not necessarily primitive types, but objects as well(`ModelState` is just one of them). Serializing that would not only not working because json doesn't accept python objects, but you could also serialize a lot of meta data that's not used.

Check out [json official website](http://www.json.org/) to see what data types are json serializable. The fix would be either using [django model serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/serialization/), or manually create a dict that in compliance to json format.

Answer (score 0):

`object` is not one of those types. Dictionaries, lists (maybe tuples), floats, strings, integers, bools, and None I *believe* are the types that Python can serialize into JSON natively.

However, it looks like Django [has some built-in serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/serialization/) that may work for you.

I'm guessing that

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize("json", OrgInvite.objects.filter(token=100))
```

should work for you

Comment: No, the serializer expects a queryset not a model instance.

Comment: Ah... so it'd need to be more than just the one result, then.

Comment: So you can do `OrgInvite.objects.filter(token=100)` to get a queryset.

Comment: That will serialize the instance inside a list, which is incorrect.