# How to pass a queryset from django to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, json, django

I want to pass a queryset from a view to a javascript function throught the template:

my `view.py`:

```
def myview(request):    
    lista=Mymodel.objects.filter(tipo=mytipo)
    context_dict['lista']=lista
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', context_dict)
```

my `template.html`:

```
  <script>
  <!--
    window.onpageshow = function() {
      myfunction('{{lista}}');
    };
  -->
  </script>
```

my `javascript.js`:

```
function myfunction(lista) {
  for (i=0; i<lista.length; i++) {
              console.log(lista[i].name)
  }
}
```

The problem is that `lista` become a string. I tried with JSONEncoder but i'm not sure how to use. I would like to avoid JsonResponse because I want to use that view for my template (if possible).

**Edit:**

There's a problem with the solution proposed in the answer:

```
TypeError: Python object is not JSON serializable
```

and the solution proposed in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555602/typeerror-python-object-is-not-json-serializable) doesn't works either (can't find `_meta` attribute called by `model_to_dict`).

JSON.parse doesn't works

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

and the problem seem to be between one path and the other:

```
myfunction(JSON.parse('['/mypath/myimage.png', '/otherpath/otherimage.png', 'etc... ']'));
```

Also in the template you must add `|safe`.

Luckly I need a list of string so:

my `view.py`:

```
def myview(request):    
    lista=Mymodel.objects.filter(tipo=mytipo)
    lista_formatted=[]
    for elem in lista:
        lista_formatted.append('/media/'+str(elem.myfield))
    lista_formatted=json.dumps(lista_formatted)
    context_dict['lista']=lista_formatted
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', context_dict)
```

my `template.html`:

```
  <script>
  <!--
    window.onpageshow = function() {
      myfunction({{lista|safe}});
    };
  -->
  </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change the line below

```
context_dict['lista']=json.dumps(lista) //note json.dumps() wraps it
```

Remove the quotes around here:

```
<script>
     <!--
    window.onpageshow = function() {
      myfunction({{lista}});//<--quote removed!
    };
-->
</script>
```

Comment: alternatively, you can do as @mkaran suggests. `JSON.parse` the string into the function, `myfunction(JSON.parse('{{lista}}'));` that

Comment: getting error Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable

Comment: @Manza, you should to convert to list `lista=list( Model.objects.all().values() )`

Comment: @Manza, you may need to use a [serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/serialization/) if your data contains any complex data values, such as a `datetime` object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first pass a queryset as a list of dictionary representing instances to the template. In order to do so in the `views.py`:

```py
def myview(request):    
    lista = Mymodel.objects.filter(tipo=mytipo)
    context_dict['lista'] = list(lista.values())
    # Also you can instead also pass the needed parameters to 'values' function, like this:
    # context_dict['lista'] = list(lista.values('field1', 'field3'))
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', context_dict)
```

Then you need to define a js variable in the template and pass the value of `lista` to it. So in the `mytemplate.html` file:

```html
<script>
    window.onpageshow = function() {
      myfunction({{ lista|safe }});  <!-- Don't forget to use 'safe' templatetag! -->
    };
</script>
```

This way you don't need to use any third-party package.